# XML files comparison

Tags: android, xml, comparison

I have transfered my sqlite database to an XML file. I am handling Database updates, so when I get some XML file from server, I need to find differences between the two XML files and then apply updates on my phone database. Problem is how to successfully compare two xml files? Do you see any approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just assume that all the data is new and just take the most recent xml file and apply all the updates to the relevant records? I know it's not *elegant* but depending on your situation, might be a good bet.

Comment: I can't afford doing that, I am afraid, I must make a comparsion and apply changes on specific tables. My DTB will be huge, so I will not delete whole and recreate it, but I will apply changes only for some tables

Answer (score 0):

If (and only if) there are the same amount of elements in both XML-files (you don't add/remove rows, only update values), you could do the following:

Use an XML parser (I use [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/)) to run through all the elements of both files, comparing one value to the other.

```
private void compareElements( Element one, Element two ) {
   //Check if the elements have children
   if( one has children AND two has children ) {
     //Recursive call this method for each child
     List oneChildren = get list of ones children
     List twoChildren = get list of twos children
     for( Element childOne in oneChildren AND Element childTwo in twoChildren )
       compareElements( childOne, childTwo ) )
   }
   else {
      //One and two have no children and we need to compare their values
      if( one.Value != two.Value )
        //Update the value in the database
   }
}
```

Note: The above is written in pseudo-code, so you have to work out the actual code yourself - but I hope it gives a general idea of what to do.

Also depending on the size of your XML-files - the above could take quite some time to run.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I cannot cope with the same amount of elemnts in both XML. On the server I might have one more column, one more table... and so on.